# Azure Web App not working with ASP.NET Core with React.js template

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have an azure web app that suddenly stopped working after months. I tried deploying again but it didn't work.
I tried creating a new web app and deploy a brand new project using the visual studio 2022 ASP.NET Core with React.js template and got the same result.

The Service Plan is B1

This is the appsetting.json (same of the template)

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "*****************************************"
  },
  "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "Project4": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
  },
"AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

This is the Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Project4.Data;
using Project4.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

If I go to Deployment tools > Console and run dotnet Project4.dll, I get this message:

Command 'starter.cmd dotnet Project4 ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 60 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed

It is .Net6.0, also tried .Net7.0

Comment: [Please follow the steps to check the start up error log.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/202561/azure-web-app-net-core-start-up-error-how-to-find)

Answer (score 0):

What was happening is that this kind of applications require a Cert. I was trying to deploy without one.